# How to resolve a memory leak in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, memory-leaks

What's the best way to resolve a GWT memory leak due to the fact that GWT is compiled in javascript and code is written in JAVA ?

Comment: can you post relevant example of code or use-case to document existing memory leak, please?

Comment: the problem is that it is a big application and absolutely don't know where to begin my search. This is why I ask it ;)

Comment: @JeromeCance Did you find a solution? What about memory Leaks in SuperDevMode?

Comment: This is quite a long time ago that I had this problem. So, I don't remember it... Look at the accepted answer, for sure it helps me a lot at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can recommend 2 things:

1. Read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you.html) article
2. Nullify all references when you done with them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In GWT development mode you can use a Java profiler such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (disclaimer: JProfiler is developed by my company) to analyze the heap.

The GWT development mode should show the same leak as well, except for the less likely case that the leak related to the Javascript translation (which would then be a bug in GWT).

Comment: that's funny : I just give a try to jprofiler 1 hour before your post. Excellent product. thanks