# What are the possible reasons of Memory leaks encounter in GWT

Tags: gwt

Can any one please explain possible ways to happen memory leaks while using GWT in development mode as well live mode?

I refer the following question

[How to resolve a memory leak in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970353/how-to-resolve-a-memory-leak-in-gwt)

as found the below link in one of the answers ..

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you

They are mostly deal with Widget creations and browser events. is there any other possible block holes to happen memory leaks like while doing RPC's ..using much rendering methods ..etc etc??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you listed talked about how GWT avoids the kinds of memory leaks that browsers are known for - cases where nothing anywhere is referencing the dom element or the widget, but the browser still won't free it from memory. The only case you need to be careful for is when you create your own widgets that hold other widgets - in that situation you need to be careful about invoking attach and detach methods on each child. Sticking with known-good containers and panels will totally save you from this, as well as never invoking attach or detach methods directly.

Beyond that, memory leaks are just like every other kind of development - we need to be careful about keeping references of things you aren't using any more. I disagree with some of the answers in the linked question - Java memory leak tools aren't great at helping to track those objects over Dev Mode, since they think about the JVM and Java objects, not Browsers and JavaScript.

Instead, compile with style set to PRETTY, and use a tool like Chrome's Inspector. That can be used to look at objects that are consuming memory, and tell what is holding on to them. The strategy is the same as with any other heap analysis tool (JProfiler, VisualVM, etc). And the standard rules for writing code apply - if you are holding on to an object you don't need, null it out or remove it from the collection that is holding it. Clearly if you still need it, keep it - and instead something higher up should letting go of *that*.