# How to detect Memory Leaks in GWT SuperDevMode Applications?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, memory-leaks

I know that for Java there is [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). But these tools are for Java based Applications. GWT SuperDevMode serves JavaScript so this might not work here.

I found a similar article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970353/how-to-resolve-a-memory-leak-in-gwt), but it does not answer my question.

**Is there a way to detect memory leaks in a GWT application using SuperDevMode?**

Comment: You might want to use Chrome's built-in Javascript Memory Profiler: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling